# USB Device communication performance for packaged Apps

Tags: windows, desktop-bridge, winui-3

I have written a console app which accesses a special USB camera using an SDK provided by the manufacturer. The app itself works perfectly fine. However, as soon as it gets packaged and executed by a WinUI 3 app, the communication with the device takes 100x as long.
I have tried Process Explorer/Monitor and WinDbg, but besides finding out, that it spends most of the time in a `WaitForMultipleObjectsEx` call, I couldn't get any further information.

Is there any fundamental difference when apps run sandboxed with regards to device communication?

Comment: Have you enable [Webcam](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/simple-camera-preview-access) capability in the package project?

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't change anything. The camera is a special device with a custom driver and only recognized as such, not as a webcam.
What I'm wondering is why the communication with the driver can be different depending on whether my app is being executed standalone or packaged.

Comment: The packaged app run in the sandbox, so it need to enable specific capability to access device.

Comment: if you used custom driver please refer [How to add USB device capabilities to the app manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/updating-the-app-manifest-with-usb-device-capabilities) to add vid and pid in the manifest file.